# Calculating the equivalent value of 2 resistors or capacitors

Tags: c#, beginner, floating-point

I started learning C# and this is my first "project". Its main purpose is to calculate the equivalent value of two resistors or capacitors connected in either series or parallel.

I just finished it and was wondering if you could review it for me. I'm open to learning what's bad, what's good (if it even has any in it) and how I can improve it.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool goAgain = true;
        while (goAgain)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("Hello! This is my app for calculating the equivalent of RESISTORS or CAPACITORS \nconnected in SERIES or in PARALLEL: ");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter when you are ready to start!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("First tell me are we using RESISTORS or CAPACITOR ? \nType R or C :");
            string type = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Okay whats the connection? In SERIES or in PARALLEL? Type S or P: ");
            string connection = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Okay! Whats the value of the first one?");
            decimal valueOfTheFirstOne = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("What is its factor?\n1.Pico\n2.Nano\n3.Micro\n4.Mili\n5.Normal\n6.Kilo\n7.Mega\n8.Giga\n9.Tera");
            decimal factorOfTheFirstOne = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Okay! And the second?");
            decimal valueOfTheSecondOne = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("What is its factor?\n1.Mili\n2.Micro\n3.Nano\n4.Pico\n5.Normal\n6.Kilo\n7.Mega\n8.Giga\n9.Tera");
            decimal secondFactor = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch ((int)factorOfTheFirstOne)
            {
                case 1:
                    factorOfTheFirstOne = 0.001m;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    factorOfTheFirstOne = 0.000001m;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    factorOfTheFirstOne = 0.000000001m;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    factorOfTheFirstOne = 0.000000000001m;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    factorOfTheFirstOne = 1.0m;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    factorOfTheFirstOne = 1000m;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    factorOfTheFirstOne = 1000000m;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    factorOfTheFirstOne = 1000000000m;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    factorOfTheFirstOne = 1000000000000m;
                    break;
            }
            switch ((int)secondFactor)
            {
                case 1:
                    secondFactor = 0.001m;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    secondFactor = 0.000001m;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    secondFactor = 0.000000001m;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    secondFactor = 0.000000000001m;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    secondFactor = 1.0m;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    secondFactor = 1000m;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    secondFactor = 1000000m;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    secondFactor = 1000000000m;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    secondFactor = 1000000000000m;
                    break;
            }
            switch (type.ToUpper())
            {
                case "R":
                    switch (connection.ToUpper())
                    {
                        case "S":
                            decimal rEquvelent = (valueOfTheFirstOne * factorOfTheFirstOne) + (valueOfTheSecondOne * secondFactor);
                            Console.WriteLine("Re = " + rEquvelent);
                            break;

                        case "P":
                            rEquvelent = ((valueOfTheFirstOne * factorOfTheFirstOne) * (valueOfTheSecondOne * secondFactor)) / ((valueOfTheFirstOne * factorOfTheFirstOne) + (valueOfTheSecondOne * secondFactor));
                            Console.WriteLine("Re= " + rEquvelent);
                            break;

                    }
                    break;
                case "C":
                    switch (connection.ToUpper())
                    {
                        case "S":
                            decimal cEquevelent = ((valueOfTheFirstOne * factorOfTheFirstOne) * (valueOfTheSecondOne * secondFactor)) / ((valueOfTheFirstOne * factorOfTheFirstOne) + (valueOfTheSecondOne * secondFactor));
                            Console.WriteLine("Ce= " + cEquevelent);
                            break;
                        case "P":
                            cEquevelent = (valueOfTheFirstOne * factorOfTheFirstOne) + (valueOfTheSecondOne * secondFactor);
                            Console.WriteLine("Ce= " + cEquevelent);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to calculate again? YES or NO");
            string goAgainAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (goAgainAnswer.ToUpper())
            {
                case "YES":
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;
                case "NO":
                    goAgain = false;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("See ya!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.

Comment: I believe we have to avoid any UX discussions here :)

Answer (score 3):

The major problem in the code is the absence of the verification of the user's input. For example, `Decimal.Parse` may throw `FormatException`, or `OverflowException`. Perhaps, you should also verify that the values are positive (you are going to accept only the passive components, aren't you?)

Huge switches on the factors can be replaced by simple formulas.

Switches on the component types and serial/parallel connections can be greatly simplified if you recall what is the impedance (~R for the resistor and ~1/C for the capacitor)

Minor issues with the code style like inconsistent variables naming (e.g. `factorOfTheFirstOne` and `secondFactor`

Answer (score 2):

You are copy-pasting some portions of your code, eg.:

```
switch ((int)factorOfTheFirstOne)
{
    case 1:
        factorOfTheFirstOne = 0.001m;
        break;
    case 2:
        factorOfTheFirstOne = 0.000001m;
        break;
    // ...
}

switch ((int)secondFactor)
{
    case 1:
        secondFactor = 0.001m;
        break;
    // ...
```

These switches are identical. It bloats the codebase and hurts readability and maintanability. Aim for code reuse instead. In this particular case, you could create a method converting factors (expressed as 1, 2, 3 etc.) into actual values (0.001m, etc.) and call it twice in your code, cutting down on needless repetition.

Nesting `switch` constructs isn't good practice, either - it's not very readable. Try to refactor your code into methods.

Having the entirety of your program in `static void Main()` is not recommended.

Also, as @Michael has already pointed out, you're not validating user input at all. One typo and your app will crash, or fail to work as expected.